Is there any way to identify mouse click event on MacOS 14.2 and then it will invoke a function for generating a UI element's XML of a dialog
I am currently trying to develop a feature for MacOS where I need to identify the mouse click event and then it will capture the dialog's UI elements which can be written in the XML format. I am using python language using pycharm as IDE
    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        self.listener.stop()
        self.path = os.path.join(self.saved_config.work_loc_folder, self.active_dlg.lstrip("*") + ".png")
        self.xml_path = os.path.join(self.saved_config.work_loc_folder, self.active_dlg.lstrip("*") + ".xml")
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(self.path)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self.path))
        self.cap.root.deiconify()  # for open maximized window
        self.timer.window.destroy()
        activeAppName = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activeApplication()['NSApplicationName']
        x1, y1, width, height = pygetwindow.getWindowGeometry(activeAppName)

        architecture = platform.machine()

        if architecture == 'x86_64':
            # Code for x64 Mac architecture
            x1 = 2 * x1
            y1 = 2 * y1
            x2 = x1 + (2 * width)
            y2 = y1 + (2 * height)
        elif architecture == 'arm64':
            # Code for arm64 Mac architecture
            x2 = x1 + width
            y2 = y1 + height

        im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)))
        im.save(self.path)

I have this function which captures the screenshot of the dialog similarly it should capture the xml also for the captured dialog.
